# NodeJS - how to make version 6.9.1 permanent?

Tags: node.js, npm, centos

I have node v6.12.2 on my CentOS 7.4. But i must need to keep v6.9.1 so when i do following it works but after reboot or logout its not kept.

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install nodejs
sudo yum install npm
npm install forever -g
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.13.1/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bash_profile
nvm list-remote
nvm install v6.9.1
# nvm use 6.9.1
Now using node v6.9.1
```

Comment: I reference the path to each node version on my server (since several of my apps run on different node versions). e.g. `/home/asykes/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node`. I suppose that's quite longwinded though, if all your apps run on the same version.

Comment: Or just run `nvm alias default 6.9.1` - bit simpler ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `nvm alias default 6.9.1`

---

#### According to the [NVM Documentation](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#listing-versions)

> To set a default Node version to be used in any new shell, use the
>   alias `default`:
>
> ```
> nvm alias default node
> ```

*Note that this sets the latest version to default though...*

---

#### So in your case, you'd do:

```
# Install the version that you would like 
nvm install 6.9.1

# Set 6.1.0 (or another version) as default
nvm alias default 6.9.1
```

---

#### Run different Apps under Different Versions

Alternatively, if you need to use different versions for different applications on your server, you could have something like this in your crontab file:

```
@reboot forever start -c /home/your-name/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node /path/to/app1/server.js

@reboot forever start -c /home/your-name/.nvm/versions/node/v0.11.0/bin/node /path/to/retro/app/server.js    

@reboot forever start -c /home/your-nodenode /path/to/modern/app/server.js
```

*Personally this is my preferred approach, as if you have 20 or 30 node applications, it's easier to specify their own versions, rather than just relying on the servers current version.*

Comment: I get error: `# nvm install v6.7.0
######################################################################## 100.0%
Checksums empty
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
Now using node v6.7.0
`

Comment: Applied after above error still valid? `# nvm alias default 6.7.0
default -> 6.7.0 (-> v6.7.0)`

Comment: still showing `# /usr/bin/node --version` version v6.12.2, even applied nvm alias default 6.7.0

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like an issue with your installation. Did you install if via the official source (https://github.com/creationix/nvm), or through a third party (like homebrew or another package manager)?

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you post some info about your system? OS? Bash or ZSH, or something else? nvm version? That'll make it a lot easier to help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Works! CentOS 7.4**

## Step 1

Go back from NEW to OLD.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.13.1/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bash_profile
nvm list-remote
nvm install v6.7.0
nvm use 6.7.0
Now using node v6.7.0
nvm alias default 6.7.0
whereis node
node: /usr/bin/node /usr/share/node /root/.nvm/v6.7.0/bin/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz
/root/.nvm/v6.7.0/bin/node --version
v6.7.0
```

## Step 2

Run as service.

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/node-server1.service
[Unit]
Description=Node-Server1
#Requires=After=mysql.service       # Requires the mysql service to run first

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/.nvm/v6.7.0/bin/node /home/www/html/server.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=1                       # Restart service after 10 seconds if node service crashes
StandardOutput=syslog               # Output to syslog
StandardError=syslog                # Output to syslog
SyslogIdentifier=nodejs-server1
#User=<alternate user>
#Group=<alternate group>
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=1337

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

## Step 3

```
systemctl enable node-server1.service
systemctl start node-server1.service
tail -f /var/log/messages
```